Blazor buttons work in child page but not home page (new Blazor WebApp project)
I cannot get a button to work on the home page or on a component living on the home page.  A secondary page with the same code works.
This is my home page where the click does not work.  Pressing it has no affect.
@page "/"


<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

<MyComponent  />

@code
{
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}

This is the MyComponent that lives on the Home page.  It has a copy/paste of the home page code, and the click does nothing
<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}

Then here is the Counter page that comes with the project.  The button click works here.
@page "/counter"
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}

The only difference is the @rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly on the Counte.razor page, but if I put that on the home page then the app crashes.
This is the basic project created using the new Blazor WebApp project.  I'm on the latest VS (17.10.3) using .NET 8.

In this project template the Home page is server side while the Counter page is WASM.  That's why the Home page was not responding.
